# How to use mongoose to get the given range documents?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get the documents from A - B (both A and B are dynamic)
the first thought came to me is using limit() and skip() API , 
but I didn't find limit() API in mongoose, so  if anybody know other api to make it?

Comment: Could you specify what A and B are? Are you looking for indexes in the collection?

Comment: thx , problem solved,  mongoose does have limit() API, I miss it  ， A-B : for example : there are 500 datas in database I want to get the data from  5 to 61 , so I need to skip 1-4  and limit the data within (56) datas